# Laptop shuts down on lid close

Tags: 10.04, power-management, shutdown

When I close the lid of my Asus X77JQ, lucid shuts it down automatically after five minutes. I want to be able to sleep in the same room as my laptop, so I would like to be able to close the lid without it shutting down. How can I do this?

The power options lid close option is set to do nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Actions to take when closing the laptop lid are configured with command [gnome-power-preferences](http://projects.gnome.org/gnome-power-manager/gpp.html) (menu: System -> Preferences -> Power management)

You will need to set two options: "When laptop lid is closed" to "Do nothing", and also "Put computer to sleep when inactive for" to "Never" (otherwise the laptop won't sleep automatically when you close the lid, but will soon afterwards because it's inactive).  Note that these options have separate values for "AC power" and "Battery power": of course, you'll have to configure the correct one for your case (or both).

*Note: You may have to run the following command for the option to show up:
`gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_ac "nothing"`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run this in terminal;

`gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_ac "nothing"`

It's some sort of regression; if the option does show up on it's own it does nothing.

Comment: This was true for me on 10.10 as well. Thanks!